# Aspx Views in Mvc 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

In **visual studio 2013** when you create a new **mvc 5** project there is no way of adding an **ASPX** view.

You can add **razor** views normally and it works perfectly.

What is the solution here?

Do I need to add a new scaffolding template to VS so it can add ASPX views?

Some say currently it only supports Razor and ASPX is going to be added later. Is it updated yet?

Screenshots added:

[image]

Add view screen:

[image]

Comment: The 2013 Preview didn't have ASPX support but the RTM does. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I can add ASPX views to MVC 5 projects just fine.

Comment: @jebar8 : I have RTM too but There is no ASPX view option! Attaching Screenshot now.

Comment: @jebar8 : Checkout my screenshots. How can you do that? Is yours different from mine?

Comment: Yep, on the Add View dialog I have a dropdown where I can select Razor or ASPX. I don't know what's different. My only other suggestion would be to try installing the 2013 Update 1 RC and see if that update gives you the option.

Comment: @jebar8 : I think you are creating MVC 4 project. I have tested this on my other computers. Looks like there is no ASPX option in MVC 5. Can you attach an screenshot?

Comment: Yes, I was looking at an existing MVC 4 project that I thought had been upgraded. /facepalm

Sorry, no ASPX option (yet) in MVC 5. Did you try installing Update 1 and see if it was there?

Comment: It's RC and I prefer to wait for RTM. Also there is no mention of ASPX view engine in release note of that update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are still able to use the 2012 Templates for MVC 4 with 2013 if you need to use ASPX views.  If you use MVC selection from ASP.NET Web project, then you don't seem to have any option other than Razor, unless you can download it with NuGet.

Kirk

Comment: I figured that out a while ago. There is no option to add an ASPX view, but you can use aspx files as before. just add a file with .aspx extension and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

From ASP.NET MVC 5, there is no option to select an ASPX View Engine only just RAZOR :
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/87cf9775-242b-4eb6-923d-7c83106d0293/visual-studio-2017-mvc-web-application-controller-add-view-missing-aspx-rendering-only-razor?forum=visualstudiogeneral